# How to validate/display a message If Queue connected

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I was able to connect to IBM MQ from local & listen, do processing.

Once I deploy to open shift ( ports are open though), I am not seeing it is processing messages by going into  @JmsListener.

Is there a way we can check/display a message once connected to Queue.

What might be wrong in my case.

```
@Component
public class SampleMessageReceiver {

  @Autowired private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  @Autowired private UrlsConfig urlsConfig;

  @JmsListener(
      destination = "${ibm.mq.channel}",
      containerFactory = "myListenerContainerFactory",
      selector = "JMSCorrelationID='c9d5e2d7c5c3e3c9d6d54040404040404040404040404040'")
  public void processSampleMessage(@Valid SampleMessage sampleMessage) {
      System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In process SampleMessages ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n");

  }

  }
```

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging.

Comment: I tried logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG in application.properties file. it's not logging anything

Comment: If it's logging nothing at all then the application is not starting.

Comment: From an MQ perspective you can use the MQSC command `DISPLAY CONN(*) TYPE(ALL) ALL` and look for your application name or the queue name. Or also try, `DISPLAY QSTATUS(q-name) TYPE(HANDLE)`. If it doesn't show up your application hasn't connected to the queue manager or opened the queue  yet.

Comment: yeah, not knowing about individual steps is one of the (few) disadvantages of a dependency-injection framework like Spring. In a 'standard' JMS code your call to connect to the queue would simply block until connected.